# ¿Cómo hago que esta búsqueda secuencial funcioné?

Tags: java

¿Cómo hago que esta búsqueda secuencial funcioné? Siento que todo está bien pero el código no me funciona

```
public class BusquedaSecuencial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arreglo[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,};
        int dato;
        //para saber si ya encontramos o no el valor
        boolean band = false;

        out.println("Digite un número del 1 al 10 para buscarlo en el arreglo");
        dato = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 8 && band == false) {
            if (arreglo[i] == dato) {
                band = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (band == false) {
            out.println("El número no se encontró en el arreglo.");
        } else {
            out.println("El número se ha encontrado en el arreglo en la posición: " + (i - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Te falta hacer algo con la variable `entrada`. Fíjate en cómo estás pidiendo al usuario que introduzca el número. ¿Y `entrada`?

Comment: Lo corregí así: "out.println("Digite un número del 1 al 10 para buscarlo en el arreglo");
        dato = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());" pero tampoco me funciona

Comment: Tienes que utilizar `entrada` no `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenias un par de problemas:

El primero no estabas recogiendo el dato que introducía el usuario.

El segundo no estabas imprimiendo nada, ya que estas escribiendo `out.println` y es:

> System.out.println();

Te dejo el código corregido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BusquedaSecuencial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arreglo[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,};
        int dato;
        int i = 0;   
        //para saber si ya encontramos o no el valor
        boolean band = false;

        System.out.println("Digite un número del 1 al 10 para buscarlo en el arreglo");
        dato = entrada.nextInt();

        while (i < 8 && band == false) {

            if (arreglo[i] == dato) {

                band = true;
            }

            i++;
        }

        if (band == false) {

            System.out.println("El número no se encontró en el arreglo.");

        } else {

            System.out.println("El número se ha encontrado en el arreglo en la posición: " + (i - 1));
        }

        entrada.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya logré que encontrará mi arreglo, mi duda es la siguiente: Cómo hago para que la posición me la tiré de 1 a los siguientes números? Porque si pongo 1 me dice que está en la posición 0

Comment: Sencillo. En el `System.out.println` donde a `i` le estas restando 1, no se lo restes. Imprime directamente la `i`

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente cambia `in.readLine()` por `entrada.nextLine()`, el problema está en los nombres de las variables.